# Concat function has not be run in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I run my whole SQL query then I got an error. `CONCAT()` function has not be run while execution:

```
..... concat(cast(col1 as varchar2(10)),'-', col2) = 'value'
```

Below this one is part of the query but I stuck on this line only. Why `Concat` function has not be run.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT function takes only 2 arguments. You must be getting `invalid number of Arguments` here.

Use

```
... col1||'-'||col2 = 'value'....
```

No need to explicitly cast your variable here. Oracle will implicitly handle this.